# How to make a floating CMFCToolbar nonmovable

Tags: mfc, toolbar

First I make my CMFCToolbar permanent with
m_wndMyToolBar.SetPermament(TRUE);  // it removes the CLOSE Button

Now, how can I achieve that the user can not move the permanent CMFCToolbar?

I have tried to subclass the CMFCToolbar, but the ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE & ON_WM_NCMOUSEMOVE are never called inside this class.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix all toolsbars just remove

```
 EnableDocking(CBRS_ALIGN_ANY);
```

In your CMainFrame class.

To handle a single bar, try to overwrite `FloatControlBar` and return FALSE.

The final and best to prevent floating fr a special bar is to overwrite `OnBeforeFloat` and return FALSE. This function is called by `FLoatControlBar`

The final way to prevent anything is to capture `WM_NCHITTEST`. Handle it and return `HTCLIENT` or eventually `HTNOWHERE`.

Comment: That is the reverse way. I don't want the toolbar "docked" at top,left right,bottom.
I use now OnBeforeDock() to prevent Docking the toolbar. But the toolbar is still moveable.

Comment: Added additional aspect to answer

Comment: Handling WM_NCHITTEST works in docked mode,  but is still movable in floating mode. :(

Comment: Let it not float... Otherwise the toolbar is wrapped into a movable window. You can't protect this.